# uniform pareto system error

Tags: bayesian, prior, uniform-distribution, pareto-distribution

Let $X\sim U(0,\theta)$. Given a sample  of size n, the likeliohood function is $l(\theta \mid x)=\frac{1}{\theta^n}$ Consider a pareto prior distribution $\theta\sim pareto(k,a)$ with density $\frac{ak^a}{\theta^{a+1}}$ with $\theta >k > 0$. By bayes theorem the posteori density is given by above, but this does not coincide with the correct value $\operatorname{pareto(a+n,max\{k,x_{max}\})}$.

$p(\theta\mid x)=\frac{\frac{1}{\theta^n}\frac{ak^a}{\theta^{a+1}}}{\int_k^\infty\frac{1}{\vartheta^n}\frac{ak^a}{\vartheta^{a+1}}}\ne \operatorname{pareto(a+n,max\{k,x_{max}\})}$

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong, i.e. what is the integration border?

Comment: Please explain how you obtained your expression for $p(\theta\mid x),$ since evidently it doesn't depend on $x$ at all!

Comment: @whuber I obtained this expression by formula from wikipedia and just plugged in prior and a-priori-density, but I have seen that the correct expression should be the one on the right and this is not equal to my result, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I fixed this problem by taking the integral from $max(x_1,\dots,x_n, k )$ intsead of k to $\infty$, but why is it so and why is the lower bound not simply $k$?

Comment: The value of the Pareto PDF for any $x_i \lt k$ is, by definition, zero.  You haven't accounted for that in your formula for the distribution.  Your integral formula cannot be correct because it doesn't depend on $x$ at all.

Comment: So the error is not the border of integration, but I have to add an indicator function in the likelihhod? Could you please state the correct formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bayes' theorem, it is often simpler to work using proportionality, ignoring the constant-of-integration completely.  This lets you establish the kernel of the posterior density, and this usually lets you identify the posterior distribution and add in the appropriate constant-of-integration at the end.  Now, in your case you have  $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \text{IID U}(0, \theta)$ with prior $\theta \sim \text{Pareto}(k, a)$.  If we define $k_n \equiv \max \{k, x_1, ..., x_n \}$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p (\theta | \boldsymbol{x}) \propto L_\boldsymbol{x}(\theta) p(\theta) 
&= \frac{1}{\theta^n} \mathbb{I}(\theta \geqslant \max \{x_1, ..., x_n \}) \cdot \frac{a k^a}{\theta^{a+1}} \mathbb{I}(\theta \geqslant k) \\[6pt]
&\propto \frac{1}{\theta^{n+a+1}} \mathbb{I}(\theta \geqslant k_n) \\[8pt]
&\propto \text{Pareto}(\theta | k_n, n+a). \\[8pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This shows that your posterior belief is $\theta | \boldsymbol{x} \sim \text{Pareto}(k_n, n+a)$.  Hence, the full density function (including the relevant constant-of-integration) is:

$$p(\theta | \boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{(n+a)k_n^{n+a}}{\theta^{n+a+1}} \mathbb{I}(\theta \geqslant k_n).$$

This posterior is consistent with the list of conjugate posteriors [listed here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).  It is possible to obtain this same result by doing the derivation without using proportionality, so it is a useful exercise to see if you can get this.

Comment: thanks for your answer but what is bothering me is that in this table of conjugate priors an other value is derived? Could you explain me why?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior

Comment: My previous working was done assuming $k \geqslant \max \{ x_1,...,x_n \}$.  I have updated the answer to allow for the more general case, and this gives a posterior consistent with the link you provide.